# Download file works on firefox, not on other browsers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, download, header, response

in staging my download function is working fine, when I deploy in production (nas server with IIS 7.5) the same functions works only on Firefox. 
With IE, Edge and Chrome the download start but, it don't arrive to the end, and after minute, get an error.
I know that there is a lot of documentation online but I just tried a lot of solutions without result. Please help me.

```
@Page Language="VB" ContentType="text/html"

@Import Namespace="System.Data"

@Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"

@Import Namespace="System.IO"


Private SUB SDataBind()

    'Path construction
        Dim VarFileName as string = "mytest.zip"

    'Path construction
        Dim VarPath as string = "/public/mydownload" & VarFileName

    'Absolute path
        Dim VarCompletPath as string = Server.MapPath(VarPath)
        VarCompletPath = replace(VarCompletPath,"/","\")

    'Filename construction
        Dim VarLast4Char as string = right(VarFileName,4)
        Dim VarNewFilename as string = "download" & VarLast4Char

    'Headers cleaner
        Response.Clear
        Response.ClearHeaders
        Response.ClearContent

    'Send the file to the browser
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment;filename=" & VarNewFilename))
        Response.ContentType = ReturnFiletype(  right(VarFileName,4)  )
        Response.WriteFile( VarCompletPath )
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
        Response.End

end sub


'----------------------------

'Get content file type
Private function ReturnFiletype(fileExtension as string) as string  

    Select Case fileExtension

        case ".zip"
            return "application/zip"
        case ".pdf"
            return "application/pdf"
        case else
            return "application/octet-stream"
        end select

end function
```

Comment: "*and after minute, get an error*" - What error?

Comment: operation canceled

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with a more classic function

'Clean the headers
    Response.Clear
    Response.ClearHeaders
    Response.ClearContent

'Send file to browser
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", ("attachment;filename=" & VarFileName))
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(VarPath))
    Response.End

I removed the lines
   Response.Flush()
   Response.Close()